# To what game does this card belong?

Tags: identify-this-game

The card in the following picture was included, probably by mistake, in a stack of Chance cards that were in a 1936 Monopoly box that I purchased on eBay a number of years ago. It clearly has nothing to do with Monopoly but it looks really old and finding it in a 1936 box seems to confirm that it is. I am curious as to which game it belongs.

[image: Card to identify]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the images in this listing, it appears to be from the game "[Pirate and Traveler](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2326/pirate-and-traveler/images)".

Comment: No doubt, that's it. The cover is particularly amusing in that it states «INDORSED (sic) BY EDUCATORS» instead of «ENDORSED». I wonder what the educators would say about that...https://boardgamegeek.com/image/712488/pirate-and-traveler